# Batch file to add a line to multiple .txt files in folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

Batch file to add a line to multiple .txt files in folders and subfolders.

I've got the code to work on a specific file if i replace (*.txt) with (specificname.txt) but it will only work in the folder the batch file is present in

```
@echo off

set "$New_line=Your text"

for %%a in (*.txt) do (

   echo %$New_line% > "New_%%a"

   type "%%a" >> "New_%%a"

   del "%%a" 2>nul

  ren "New_%%a" "%%a"

)
```

I've got it to work in the folder the batch file is present in but needs extending to search for files within subfolders

expected result will add line to .txt files in both folder and subfolders

Comment: Well I'm afraid that you should make an attempt at the task, we're not here to write it for you, especially as you've not shown any attempt at doing it yourself. If you start by opening a Command Prompt window and enter each of your used commands one by one followed by a space, a forward slash, and a question mark, you'd get much further.

Comment: [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) has a `/R` switch...

Comment: ...which you'll see when you type the used command `for /?` at the Command Prompt as already mentioned.

Comment: '@echo off
set "$New_line=Your text"

for /R C:\folder\ %%a in (*.txt) do (
   echo %$New_line% > "New_%%a"
   type "%%a" >> "New_%%a"
   del "%%a" 2>nul
   ren "New_%%a" "%%a"
)'  just deletes all the text files in every folder and subfolder

Comment: Don't post code in comments, [edit] your question and insert it there instead! Please also read this: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There are some quirks in your code (taken from your comment):

`ren` doesn't support paths in the destination part - filename.ext only.

With `for /r`, `%%a` gives a Full Qualified File Name (drive,path,name,extension), so `_new%%a` results in an invalid FQFN (like `_New_C:\folder\subfolder\file.txt`)

You can get the needes substrings with modifiers (explained in `for /?`)

Minor improvements:
put quotes around any path or filename
swiched to another redirection syntax for the `echo` command to avoid trailing spaces.

```
@echo off
set "$New_line=Your text"
for /R "C:\folder\" %%A in (*.txt) do (
  > "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA" echo %$New_line%
  type "%%A" >> "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA"
  del "%%A" 2>nul
  ren "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA" "%%~nxA"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan,
This adds a new line at the beginning of the file, is there anyway this could add after the text that was already present in the .txt? Apologies I'm clearly a novice at this but interested in learning more.

Comment: You mean appending a fixed string to the end of the  first line of every textfile?

Comment: I mean, leaving the contents of the .txt file untouched and adding the $New_line=Your text" string on a new line at the end of the contents of that 
 .txt file - whereas the code before placed the line before the contents

Comment: uhm - like swapping the `type` and the `echo` command? But it's a lot easier: `for /r "c:\folder\" %%A in (*.txt) do >>"%%A" echo %$New_line%`. no need for temporary files - just append the line to the original files.